# Storm - Conditionally consuming stream from kafka spout?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

I have a scenario where I am posting json to a Kafka instance. I am then using a Kafka Spout to emit the stream to a bolt.

But now I would like to add additional field (call it `x`) to my json message. If `x` is `a` I would like it to be consumed by boltA, if `x` is `b` I would like it to be consumed by boltB.

Is there a way to direct the stream to the proper bolt depending on the streams contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way should be to add a `SplitBolt` that consumes from `KafkaSpout`, evaluates the field `x` , and forwards to different output streams:

```
public class SplitBolt extends BaseRichBolt {
  OutputCollector collector;

  public void prepare(...) {
    this.collector = collector;
  }

  public void execute(Tuple input) {
    Object x = ... // get field x from input
    String streamId;
    if(x == a) {
      streamId = "stream-xa";
    } else { // x == b
      streamId = "stream-xb";
    }
    collector.emit(streamId, input, input.getValues());
  }

  public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
    Fields schema = new Fields(...)
    declarer.declareStream("stream-xa", schema);
    declarer.declareStream("stream-xy", schema);
  }
}
```

When building your Topology, you connect `BoltA` to "stream-xa" and `BoltB` to "stream-xb":

```
TopologyBuilder b = new TopologyBuilder();
b.setSpout("spout", new KafkaSpout(...));
b.setBolt("split", new SplitBolt()).shuffleGrouping("spout");
b.setBolt("boltA", new BoltA()).shuffleGrouping("split", "stream-xa");
b.setBolt("boltB", new BoltB()).shuffleGrouping("split", "stream-xb");
```

As an alternative, it should also be possible, to inherit from `KafkaSpout` and emit to two different streams directly. However, the code is more tricky to get right.

Comment: Hi @Matthias J. Sax  , This can also be done by reading from a new topic of kafka altogether. say `topicXA` and `topicXB` and creating a new topology with new kafkaSpout. What are the downsides of doing this? Is creating a new topology an overhead by any means?

Comment: Well, there would be write and read and storage overhead for the Kafka cluster. If you would like to read those topics multiple times (ie with different applications) it might make sense to put the data into Kafka again. Otherwise, I don't see a big benefit to duplicate the data in Kafka.