# Storm- Routing bolt to get schema from the kafka spout

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

[Storm - Conditionally consuming stream from kafka spout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31592866/storm-conditionally-consuming-stream-from-kafka-spout)

How do i get the schema of the data inside the Split Bolt when I try to output it using the declareOutputFields().

Fields schema = new Fields(?)

How do i get the schema of the all the fields in the data inside this bolt without basically reparsing all the data and recreating it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know the schema beforehand, ie, before you process the first tuples. The method `declareOutputFields()` is called during deployment before the first call to `execute()`.

Storm cannot handle a variable schema. If you have JSON data with unknown structure, you could declare `new Fields("json")` and put the whole JSON object into a single field.